# executing a stored proc with output parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQLDEVELOPER TO make a stored procedure. this is my procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SPP
(
 inpt IN VARCHAR2,
 opt OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT U_ID 
    INTO opt 
    FROM TABLE_NAME 
   WHERE U_ID=inpt;
END;
```

so it should return the value in opt which i can then print or whatever.
i dont know how to execute it i tried running this script

```
var opt VARCHAR2;

exec SPP('test_user') := opt
```

but it doesnt work this is my first time doing stored procs and I'm really confused any help is appreciated

how do i make it run? i can make a stored proc run with input variables but with an output variable i mess up and I cant do it without using the SELECT (item) INTO format.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the procedure, you'd need to pass in a variable that the procedure can populate.  Something like

```
DECLARE
  l_output table_name.u_id%type;
BEGIN
  spp( 'test_user', l_output );
END;
```

Now, that being said, declaring a stored procedure whose only purpose is to query the database and return a value is generally the wrong architectural choice.  That's why functions exist.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function( p_input IN table_name.u_id%type )
  RETURN table_name.u_id%type
IS
  l_uid table_name.u_id%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT u_id
    INTO l_uid
    FROM table_name
   WHERE u_id = p_input;

  RETURN l_uid;
END;
```

which you can then call either in a PL/SQL block

```
DECLARE
  l_output table_name.u_id%type;
BEGIN
  l_output := some_function( 'test_user' );
END;
```

or in a SQL statement

```
SELECT some_function( 'test_user' )
  FROM dual;
```

Comment: And thanks for the tip, i was just thrown into database stuff without much exposure so i appreciate the comments. thank you very much!

Comment: Also, how would i go about printing the l_output variable? just to validate what i did was right? thanks a ton!

Comment: @user4992422 - From within a PL/SQL block, `dbms_output.put_line( l_output );`.  You'd have to configure your client to display that output, though.  In SQL*Plus, you'd run `set serveroutput on` before running your block.  In most PL/SQL IDEs (Toad, SQL Developer, etc.), there will be a DBMS Output tab/ pane/ window that you need to enable.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again!